# wp_enqueue_scripts not working with autoptimize plugin for wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, slick.js, autoptimize

I’ve installed autoptimize for WP 4.6.1 and it works great. However, I’ve noticed some scripts stopped working. All script contained in my scripts.php file are not being loaded anymore:

scripts.php

```
<?php 
function scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('placeholder-effect', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/dist/js/placeholderTypewriter.js',array('jquery') , null, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('slick-js', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js',array('jquery', 'main') , null, true);
  wp_enqueue_script('match-height', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/dist/js/matchHeight.js',array('jquery', 'main') , null, true);
  wp_enqueue_style('slick-css', '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css');
  wp_localize_script('main', 'MyAjax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
  wp_enqueue_script('main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/all.js',[] , null, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts');
```

this script is loaded from the wp_head(). However none of the scripts loaded with wp_enqueue_script are working. So here, MyAjax remains empty, and is breaking my ajax calls, all the sliders based on slick are breaking on the site and so on..

What is the workaround to make it work?
Any help is much appreciated thank you.

EDIT: I tried to exclude the scripts from autoptimize like this but it's not working:
[image]

Comment: You can exclude scripts from Autoptimize.

Comment: if you disable the auto-optimize does start working again?

Comment: Please refer to this URL https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/#%0Ahow%20does%20%E2%80%9Cexclude%20from%20optimizing%E2%80%9D%20work%3F%0A

Comment: Hi @Darshkhakhkhar yes it does work again if I disable auto optimize.

Comment: @Bhautik thank you for the link. However, I've tried but it's not working. See the screenshot in the EDIT.